Pass DTO object as parameter when performing Laravel Livewire's dispatch
I have an object of type
class OperationDtoRequest implements Wireable
{
    public $operationId, $activeUserId;
...
}

which I would like to pass as a parameter for livewire's dispatch function.
When I process the event, if I use typed parameter, i.e. OperationDtoRequest $request as input, I receive object with all fields set as null. If I remove the type, I receive an array of proper field->value pairs. Is there a way to configure livewire to automatically map these values to a proper object type?

That's a tough cookie to crack; Livewire does a lot of things underwater, and I haven't been able to trace where Livewire converts the data. Perhaps you can try and see if using __serialize and __unserialize get called?
